# Ole32 createObject "excel.application" fails in win7 64bits

Tags: haskell, com, ms-office

I managed to use the com1.2.3 library but i can only use excel if it is already openned.

I don't know why this code doesn't work;

```
main = coRun $ do
     idEx <- createObject "Excel.Application"
```

i got this error in cmd:

```
*** Exception: ComException {comException = ComError (-2147467262),
comExceptionMsg = "(0x80004002) This interface is not supported\r\n"}.
```

I read that in win7 there is maybe an impossibility to launch 64b applications from com32. Is that correct?

Anyone has a working code that will launch excel from win7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i found it. i post here since someone may be interested in the solution and may have inspiration. I read somewhere that instead of createObject , coCreateInstance should be used. 
so the following code should fire excel

```
import System.Win32.Com 
import System.Win32.Com.Automation

iidIDispatch_unsafe  = mkIID "{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

newExcel = coRun $ do 
   clsidExcel <- clsidFromProgID "Excel.Application"
   pIunknown <- coCreateInstance clsidExcel  Nothing LocalProcess iidIDispatch_unsafe
   let pExl = castIface pIunknown :: IDispatch ()
   propertySet "Visible" [inBool True]  pExl
```